# Cakephp Auth Component - Home page redirect loop

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to have a login form in my home page, the registered users should be redirected to users/index

with the below code, my home page is going to **redirect loop**
can anyone tell me where is the issue ??

**Note:-** infact it is perfectly working if i change the line to

```
$this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
```

**App Controller**

```
  public function beforeFilter(){
            $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
            $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => './', 'action' => 'index');
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index');
            $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => './', 'action' => './');
            $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';
            $this->Auth->authError= 'You need permissions to access this page';
            $this->Auth->allow('index');
            $this->set('Auth',$this->Auth);

        }
```

UsersController

```
public function login(){
        $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        if(empty($id)){
            if($this->request->is('post')){
                if($this->Auth->login()){
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());   
                }else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Username or password');
                }
            }
        }else{
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }   
    }
```

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much answered your own question here:

> **Note:-** infact it is perfectly working if i change the line to
>
> $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');

Indeed that would work and that is what it should look like. Right now, you're telling the auth component your loginAction (the action which holds your login logic) is the `index` action of the `./` controller (which doesn't even exist). I'm assuming you're confusing it with the `loginRedirect` variable, which is for setting the page to go to after successful authentication.

Comment: what if i want to have a login page @ my home page...i mean only authorized users should access my site ??

Comment: You'll automatically get redirected to the login page if you're not authenticated yet, so it's best to keep the login form seperate. But if you *really* have your mind set on it, then you'd best adjust the `/` route in `App/Config/Routes.php` to point to your login action. This does mean that users who are already logged in and go to your site root (e.g. http://www.example.com/), they will be served with the login page AGAIN.

Comment: By saying home page,do you mean that you only want Registered Users to access your site, or do you really mean just the Homepage? For example, if I am not registered, I wont be able to access your homepage, but I will be able to access www.domain.com/articles?

Comment: I have something similar to what you are looking, I think, however, I only use it when my site is offline for maintenance. When my site is offline, I use the offline.ctp layout and on that page I have a login form. At this point, only administrators are allowed to login and see the site. Everyone else may attempt to login, if they figure where to click to display the hidden form, but they will be automatically logged out. Let me know and I will post my code if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: how can i give allow access to my home, its been redirecting to users/login when i access my home which i don't want...

Answer (score 0):

If you only want Registered Users to Access Your Site you could have something like this... at least, this is how I implement something similar in my site...

In your app_controller file add the following to the beginning of your beforeFilter() function

```
function beforeFilter(){
    //Check if user was able to log in thru Auth using your form in the homepage
    if($this->isLoggedIn() == TRUE){
        $this->layout = 'default'
    }else{
        // You can created this layout with a login form and 
        // whatever else you need except <?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
        // Any registered user will be allowed to login using the form
        // and continue on to your site using the default layout
        // But it guarantees no one else can see your default site
        $this->layout = "unregistered_user"
    }
}
```

On your App_controller.php you can create this function

```
function isLoggedIn(){
    // You can also use $this->Auth->user directly in your App's beforeFilter()
    // But I just like to have functions so I can reuse
    if($this->Auth->user()){
       $loggedin= TRUE;
    }else{
        $loggedin= FALSE;
    }
    return $loggedin;
}
```

I have something similar of my site but is only used when in maintenance mode. I am still developing my site. The only problem I've seen with this way, which I have not yet have time/need to look at, is that my errors are not sent to the layout I want. Supposed a user types in http://www.mydomain.com/inexistentpage then cake transfers them to my default layout. It might be easy to fix, but I havent got time to do that yet.

NOTE: I quickly did this off the top of my head and because of it, this code is untested. However, if you have any issues please let me know and I will test it and post back.

Answer (score 0):

using `$this->requestAction(anotherController/action);` in the view might call to another controller->action. you must ensure that the another controller->action has the right permissions. or you'll get redirect loop.

solve it by adding `$this->auth->allow('action name');` to the another controller page in the beforeFilter() callback.